# Bash shell script not executing command docker entrypoint

Tags: bash, docker, cron

I have a shell script, it is not executing the "crontab" command when it is run from docker CMD. But works when I execute the file inside the docker container. What am I missing?

File entry.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Starting cron"
/usr/sbin/cron -f -L 15
crontab /etc/cron.d/cron-python
```

Docker file:

```
FROM python:3
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
COPY ./cron/entry.sh /entry.sh
COPY ./cron/crontab.txt /etc/cron.d/cron-python
RUN chmod +x /entry.sh
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron-python
CMD ["./entry.sh"]
```

cron-python:

```sh
#   crontab -e
*/1 * * * * python /app/myscript.py >> /var/log/script.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work :

```
#!/bin/sh
# start cron
echo "Starting cron"
crontab /etc/cron.d/cron-python
/usr/sbin/cron -f -L 15
```

In your version, `/etc/cron.d/cron-python` does not get installed as you asked /usr/sbin/cron to run on foreground.

Also you need to copy /app/myscript.py.